# Image that links to a node inside a colorbox in drupal

Tags: drupal, colorbox

I'm looking to have a image that when clicked loads up a node into a colorbox.

So far I'm using Colorbox and Colorbox_node modules, and have a block with this bit of code

```
< a class="colorbox-node" href="cast?width=500&height=500" >
Link to my node alised 'cast'
< /a >
```

The text link when clicked acts exactly as I want by poping up a colorbox. Though if I replace the text with an image link like:

```
< a class="colorbox-node" href="cast?width=500&height=500" >
< img src="/images/cast.png"  / >
< /a >
```

The image displays, but is not a clickable link.

Have I screwed up somewhere or is there a different way all together of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Create new View:
Add following fields in Order:
Nid
Title
Image
Body

Title: Config

```
Formatter: Image
Image Style: thumbnail
Link image to: Nothing
```

Click on REWRITE RESULTS and Select Checkbox

```
Output this field as a link
```

Set Options As follow:

```
Link Path: node/[nid]/?width=600&height=600
Checked Checkbox "Use Absolute Path"
Link Class: colorbox-node
Alt Text: [title]
```

Save your view and run view.

Click on any of your image to load the whole node content in Colorbox.
Note: You must installed Colorbox, colorbox_node module.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by AshwinP works, but remember to add a field of type Content: Nid without label and "exclude from display" checked, and put it before the image that you want to link, otherwise it will be impossible to link it to the node. Also the Image style and the alt text doesn't matter what you put in there, just go with your own settings.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't working anymore, seems that now it's need to add data-options to the link :(

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment than an answer.